# How to get the number of returning users over a custom date range using the V4 Reporting API

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to figure out how to get the number of returning users over a custom date range using the V4 Reporting API.

[image]
Like the 'All Users' row in this screenshot, but instead of the last 14 days, it should be any date range.

After reading through the documentation, the only thing I came up with, was to create cohorts for every day I want to query, and then sum up the values for each day to get the totals:

```
"reportRequests": [
  {
   "viewId": "147125344",
   "dimensions": [
    {
     "name": "ga:cohort"
    },
    {
     "name": "ga:cohortNthDay"
    }
   ],
   "metrics": [
    {
     "expression": "ga:cohortActiveUsers"
    }
   ],
   "cohortGroup": {
    "cohorts": [
     {
      "name": "date 1",
      "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
      "dateRange": {
       "endDate": "2017-07-08",
       "startDate": "2017-07-08"
      }
     },
     {
      "name": "date 2",
      "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
      "dateRange": {
       "endDate": "2017-07-09",
       "startDate": "2017-07-09"
      },
      {
       "name": "more days",
       "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
       "dateRange": {
       "endDate": "next day",
       "startDate": "next day"
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

However, this is limited by the fact that there can only be 12 cohorts in total, so I could not query more than 12 days at once.

Is there any way to get this data directly through the API?

Comment: From your question it is not clear what value you are looking for, it could be as simple as making a regular request with `ga:userType`, or if you are after user's who came on a certain date you could set up a segment `users::sequence::^ga:sessionCount==1;dateOfSession<>2014-05-20_2014-05-30` to get at the particular start date, and then just use the regular date range field for the full date range you are interested in.